# How to make UITableViewCell highlighted state persist

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableviewCell. When a user clicks the cell, Im saving the indexpath and then calling the cellforrowAtIndexpath method to get the cell and then call the SetHighlighted:TRUE on that cell.

This works fine but the problem is when I scroll up and down the tableview, the selected cell when reappears, is not highlighted. How do I make the highlighted blue color persist so the user can visually see their selection even after scrolling the table up or down?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

save the indexpath of the selected cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

and compare in `tableVIew:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // configure cell
    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath]) {
        [cell setHighlighted:YES];
    }
    else {
        [cell setHighlighted:NO];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

However, keep in mind that apple discourages the use of the cell highlight state to indicate selected cell. You should probably use `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already have an accessoryView as a detaildisclosureindicator. Thats why I wanted to highlight the cell. Would that be a problem with Apple? Whats your advice? Thanks

Comment: You can never know if it's ok with them. Sometimes they are really strict about the HIG, sometimes not so much. I would just try to submit it like it is. Worst case scenario they reject it and you change it.

Comment: Setting the cell as highlighted doesn't work. I had to use `[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`

Comment: I think it is better to bind the variable that indicate your selection to your data not to the indexPath since we can eventually reorder stuff, and the same indexPath will not be pointing to the same (data wise) cell.