# How to get image set in selectedBackgroundView in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to get the image that a `selectedBackgroundView` has associated to it (that I previously set). I have a menu like this:

[image: Menu]

This menu has three states: normal (unselected, black image), selected (blue image) and highlighted (grey image). This works fine, but there is a problem. If I highlight the selected row and then unselect it without choosing it (by dragging my finger and lifting outside the cell, for example), it will turn black instead of blue. This is expected behavior for cells that are not the selected one (as they transition between highlighted and unselected), but not for the selected row (which should transition between selected and highlighted).

This the code for my row highlighting/unhighlighting:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.cellBackgroundNormal];
    self.cellBackgroundViewHighlighted = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.cellBackgroundHighlighted];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.selectedBackgroundView);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.cellBackgroundViewSelected);
    if(cell.selectedBackgroundView == self.cellBackgroundViewSelected) {
        self.isSelected = YES;
    }
    self.highlightedIndexPath = indexPath;

    cell.backgroundView = self.cellBackgroundViewHighlighted;
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = self.cellBackgroundView;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.cellBackgroundNormal];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.highlightedIndexPath];
    }

    if(self.isSelected) {
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = self.cellBackgroundViewSelected;
        self.isSelected = NO;
    } else {
        cell.backgroundView = self.cellBackgroundView;
    }

}
```

Basically, I have a `BOOL` that checks and sees if it's selected, and should act differently according to that. However, I need to get the image that's currently in the `selectedBackgroundView` in the delegate method that handles the highlighting.

`NSLog`ging it (in the highlighting method) gives me:

```
2013-04-28 23:07:18.076 App1[6403:c07] <UIImageView: 0x75d4c20; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x75d5610>> - cell_menu_selected
2013-04-28 23:07:18.078 App1[6403:c07] <UIImageView: 0x7567350; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x75ab2d0>> - cell_menu_selected
```

As you can see, the last part is what I need, the `cell_menu_selected`. This is what tells me what image each view has. How do I extract this? The comparison is obviously not working, because it compares pointers and those are different.

Comment: You can't get the image name from a UIImageView's .image property since it's not stored.  That's probably not the best way to save state anyways since your code might break later if you change image names.

Comment: @iWasRobbed So how would I check? Any ideas? This is a rather glaring bug that I can't seem to squash.

Comment: I don't see you saving the `selectedIndexPath` anywhere.  See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5694957/308315

Comment: @iWasRobbed That's what I did now, and it fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to answer your own question with a solution and accept it so this question gets closed out.